# Accessing inherited scope in child controller using controller as syntax

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to access the scope of my parent controller (that's using controller as syntax) from my child controller (that's also using controller as).

I've tried using `bindToController: true` as well as simply declaring `scope: true` in the directive declaration, but I can't seem to get access to it.

```
angular.module("testapp").directive("testdirective", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '../Scripts/AngularJS/Partials/testdirective.html',
        scope: true,
        bindToController: true
    };
});
```

But when printing `this` from the controller I can't see anything from the parent scope:

```
function testcontroller() {
    var self = this; 

    console.log(self); 
}
```

I know that using $scope could be an easy solution, however this goes against all correct practices I've read and I don't want to mix the two ways of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

The point of `bindToController: true` is to use it with isolated scope, because its binds the properties of the scope that was passed to the isolated controller, so you wouldn't need to be using '$scope' to access the passed in values.

how about using [require](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-require-)?
Todd Motto [explains it excellent](https://toddmotto.com/directive-to-directive-communication-with-require/) .